# GCC warn when relative import file multiple times in include path list

Tags: c, gcc-warning

If a header filename exists multiple times in include path list, how can I make GCC warn me or error out, instead of choosing silently proceeding?

Consider this example:

```c
// File: alternative_1/my_include.h
#define VAL 1
```

```c
// File: alternative_2/my_include.h
#define VAL 2
```

```c
// File: main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_include.h"

int main(void) {
  printf("Using alternative_%d\n", VAL);
}
```

I do not want this to silently compile and run:

```
❯ gcc -Ialternative_2 -Ialternative_1 main.c -o main
❯ ./main
Using alternative_2
```

Comment: You don't. GCC was specifically made to behave this way so that you can override headers by putting them earlier in the path.

Comment: @MadPhysicist simply compiler stop searching on first found. Quite logical

Answer (score 0):

```
// File: alternative_1/my_include.h
int function() {
  return 1;
}
```

It is wrong. Yuo should not put any function bodies and data definitions into header files. They should only contain types declarations, definitions, extern objects declarations and static inline functions.

And answering your question - compilers only search include paths until they found the include file. Then they stop to search the rest of the directories. There is no way of changing it.

Comment: Removed definition in header file from example, but I see this is expected behavior.

Comment: You're right, apparently I didn't read carefully at all